# How to check if a value is included by a list in an effective way in sql 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to use something like an .Include function in SQL Server 2008, but I could not find the correct syntax for it. I have a sql query like below:

```
--@values has to be varchar list and start & end with comma
declare @values varchar(max) = ',7,34,37,74,85,'
select (case when @values like '%,' + m.Id + ',%' then m.Name else null end)
from #myTable m
```

So the logic is, if ID of a record matches with one of the numbers in @values list, I would like to see its name in the output list. This query is working fine, but I would like to find a more professional way to handle it, maybe like:

```
case when @values.Include(m.Id) then m.Name else null end
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: is this strictly for direct queries or are you using this from application code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest method to split a delimited string is using xquery in my experience.

Ex:

```
DECLARE @values VARCHAR(50), @XML XML
SET @values = ',7,34,37,74,85,'

SET @XML = cast(('<X>'+replace(@values,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)

SELECT N.value('.', 'VARCHAR(255)') as value FROM @XML.nodes('X') as T(N)

declare @table table (id varchar(5))
insert into @table(id)
values ('7')

select *
from @table y
where exists (SELECT 1 FROM @XML.nodes('X') as T(N) where N.value('.', 'VARCHAR(255)') = y.id)
```

Comment: Also I am receiving "Implicit conversion from data type xml to nvarchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. " after running the line: SET @XML = cast(('<X>'+replace(@values,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)

Comment: You can do this to cast an nvarchar to varchar: 'SET @XML = cast(('<X>'+replace(convert(varchar(max),@values),',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml) ' but if you are actually using unicode characters this may not work well for you.  If you aren't using max, you should specify a length.

Comment: When I change VARCHAR to NVARCHAR in select N.Value, error received:

SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_WARNINGS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

Comment: You can add `SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;` before running in SSMS

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data/list is not required to be structered as a comma separated list you could either use [IN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177682.aspx), [EXISTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188336.aspx) or [SOME / ANY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms175064.aspx)

If it is unavoidable you could use JiggsJedi way but since you asked for a fast way you should try to store the data in a way that in can be processed faster and does not require additional work to be queried.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling this code from an application, you might want to consider using [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx) and a stored procedure to do this.

First, you would need to create a table type to use with the procedure:

```
create type dbo.Ids_udt as table (Id int not null);
go
```

Then, create the procedure:

```
create procedure dbo.get_names_from_list (
  @Ids as dbo.Ids_udt readonly
) as 
begin;
  set nocount, xact_abort on;

  select t.Name
  from t
    inner join @Ids i
      on t.Id = i.Id
end;
go
```

Then, assemble and pass the list of Ids to the stored procedure using a `DataTable` added as a `SqlParameter` using `SqlDbType.Structured`.

Table Valued Parameter Reference:

- [SQL Server 2008 Table-Valued Parameters and C# Custom Iterators: A Match Made In Heaven! - Leonard Lobel](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/)
- [Table Value Parameter Use With C# - Jignesh Trivedi](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/table-value-parameter-use-with-C-Sharp/)
- [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server and .NET - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)
- [Maximizing Performance with Table-Valued Parameters - Dan Guzman](http://www.dbdelta.com/maximizing-performance-with-table-valued-parameters/)
- [Maximizing throughput with tvp - sqlcat](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2013/09/23/maximizing-throughput-with-tvp/)
- [How to use TVPs with Entity Framework 4.1 and CodeFirst](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179481/Code-First-Stored-Procedures)

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
Drop table #Temp

Create table #Temp (ID INt ,Name varchar(5))
INSERT into #Temp
SELECT 7,'AA'  Union all
SELECT 34,'BA' Union all
SELECT 37,'CA' Union all
SELECT 74,'DA' Union all
SELECT 85,'TA'

DECLARE @values varchar(max) = ',,,,,,7,,34,,,74,85,,,,'   --If extra commas are added in starting or end or in between of string it could handle
 SET @values=','+@values+','

SELECT @values= LEFT(STUFF(@values,1,1,''),LEN(@values)-2)

DECLARE @SelectValuesIn TABLE(Value INT)
    INSERT INTO @SelectValuesIn
     SELECT    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data  
        FROM  
        (
            SELECT   
                 CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@values, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  

        ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a); 

 SELECT * FROM #Temp WHERE ID IN(SELECT Value from @SelectValuesIn)
```